# why am i getting this error only on amazon aws EC2 and not on other instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, web-crawler

why am i getting this error only on amazon aws ec2 instances

```
  wget www.lowes.com
  http://www.lowes.com/
  Resolving www.lowes.com (www.lowes.com)... 
  Connecting to www.lowes.com (www.lowes.com)||:80... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
  ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

and when i try `wget www.lowes.com` the same on my local vmware (non amazon ec2 instances) instances it works why so

means could this be possible??

Comment: Have you opened port 80 on your EC2 instances security group?

Comment: yes i have it open and i even tried `wget www.google.com` it worked

Comment: Guessing.. The web server OR the reverse proxy in front on www.lowes.com is configured to deny connection based on the IP address of the originating request.

Comment: yes i too guess the same , so for that i tried to to terminate the instances and create a new instances but still it is the same

Comment: lowes.com would have blocked the entire ip range - not just one particular ip.

Comment: entire ip range could this be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`www.lowes.com` appears to be specifically blocking the AWS port range.

Accessing the site from a web browser on a Windows EC2 instance returns the message "You don't have permission to access "http://www.lowes.com/" on this server."

It is not being caused by any configurations you have set.

Comment: ok means `lowes.com` considers every request from aws ec2 as a bad request and blocks it